# Sharepoint 2013 timerjob choose server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

is it possible to specify the server on which to run timer-job?

Write in code or when deployed. I want to run on one app server.

Answer (score 0):

[Have you tried the below code?](https://bhandariasb.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/how-to-prevent-sharepoint-timer-jobs-from-running-multiple-times/)

```
public StartWorkflow(string jobName, SPWebApplication webApplication) : base(jobName, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
{
this.Title = “Start Workflow Timer Job”;
}
```

**SPJobLockType.None** – The timer job runs on every machine in the farm on which the parent service is provisioned, unless the job I associated with a specified server in which case it runs on only that server (and only if the parent service is provisioned on the server).

**SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase** – Locks the content database. A timer job runs one time for each content database associated with the Web application.

**SPJobLockType.Job** – Locks the timer job so that it runs only on one machine in the farm.

Comment: Yes, I use SPJobLockType.Job. But, timerJob run on Web 1 or Web2 servers. I want to run on one of app server (App1 or App2).

Answer (score 0):

Inherit the timer job from `SPServerJobDefinition`.

```
 class MyCustomTimerJob : SPServerJobDefinition
    {
        public MyCustomTimerJob()
            : base()
        {
        }
        public MyCustomTimerJob(string jobName, SPServer server)
            : base(jobName, server)
        {
            this.Title = jobName;
        }
        public override void Execute(SPJobState _jobState)
        {
            // to do
        }
    }
```

Then specify the server.

```
MyCustomTimerJob myJob = new MyCustomTimerJob("My Timer Job", SPFarm.Local.Servers["Server"]);
```

Here is a [thread](https://weblogs.asp.net/spano/where-is-my-sharepoint-2010-custom-timer-job-running) which would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the job runs on the server from where you deployed the WSP.

You can force that by "hard-coding" the server you need the job to run on, by using the appropriate `SPServerJobDefinition` constructor, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249024.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure through "manage content database". If you want to specify preferred server for timer jobs for particular web application go to Central administration > Manage content databases > Select appropriate web app and click on the content database from the list > In "Preferred Server for Timer Jobs" drop-down list select required a server.